# iPad application is stuck while installing into the device

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, architecture, armv7

My App works fine in the iPad simulator. However, when I try to install it to device, it is giving the below error. I tried changing armv7/armv6/both, but nothing seems to resolve this error.

```
<Warning>: Can't get bundle identifier for process 383
<Error>: 0x3c5000 do_preflight_verification: Incorrect architecture at /var/tmp/install_staging.WJpLQT/foo_extracted/Payload/Cordo
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> changing arnv7/arnv6/both but nothing seems to resolve this error

Use `armv7`and `armv6` instead of `arnv7` and `arnv6`.

Also include `arm64`, `armv7`, `armv7s`.

Please reset your architecture settings as below

[image]

or

Choose your valid architecture as `Standared Architectures(armv7,armv7s)` and valid architecture as only `armv7`

Comment: I was using armv7 not *n. Sorry it was typo in initial comment. if I use what you have suggested, i am getting below error.      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from

      _OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewController in ViewController.o

  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVViewController", referenced from:

      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ViewController in ViewController.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: so choose your valid architecture as "Standared Architectures(armv7,armv7s) and Valid architecture as only "armv7" . let me know the results.